# For some integers $m,n$,proving that $p\mid m$

Tags: number-theory

Assume $p$ is a prime number such that $p\equiv 1 \pmod3$, and $q=\lfloor \frac{2p}{3}\rfloor$.

If:
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot2} +\frac{1}{3\cdot4} +\cdots+\frac{1}{(q-1)\cdot q} =\frac{m}{n}$$

For some integers $m,n$, what is the proof that $p\mid m$

Comment: I changed the dots to multiplications, I hope that is what you ment.

Comment: Also is it clear that $q-1$ is odd, or could the sum possibly end with $\frac{1}{q(q+1)}$?

Comment: @SimonMarkett $q-1$ is odd since $p$ is of the form $3k+1$, so $q = \lfloor (6k+2)/3 \rfloor = \lfloor 2k+2/3 \rfloor= 2k.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=3k+1$ and $H_n$ denote the n-th harmonic number. Since $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$ (1) the sum in the question is $$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^q \frac{ (-1)^{i+1} }{i} = H_{2k}-H_k.$$

Working in mod $p$, we add $p$ to the denominator of each term in $H_k$ : $$ H_{2k} - H_k \equiv H_{2k} + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{p-i} = H_{p-1} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \left( \frac{1}{i} + \frac{1}{p-i}\right)\equiv \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \left( \frac{1}{i} + \frac{1}{-i}\right)=0.
$$

proving the result.

---

Using (1) we see that $$\frac{1}{1\cdot2} +\frac{1}{3\cdot4} +\cdots+\frac{1}{(q-1)\cdot q} = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdots  + \frac{1}{q-1} - \frac{1}{q}.$$

The series is almost like a Harmonic number but it has alternating signs, so we add and subtract 2*even terms:

$$\frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdots  + \frac{1}{q-1} - \frac{1}{q} = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{q} \right) -2 \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{q} \right).$$

The factor of 2 cancels with the denominator of every term in the second bracket. Remembering that $q=2k$ gives $$ \left( 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2k} \right) - \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{k} \right)= H_{2k} - H_k.$$

Comment: Great answer! I'd prefer to finish $H_{p-1}=\sum_{i\in(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times}i^{-1}=\sum_{i\in(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times}i=0\in\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$, but that really just a matter of taste.

Comment: @Marc That is a very nice proof of that fact, I wish I'd thought of that!

Comment: Is that mean $m=0$ ?

Comment: @MohammedAl-mubark It means $m=0$ working mod $p$, which means $m$ is divisible by $p.$

Comment: But the sum should be positive value not zero .

Comment: @MohammedAl-mubark Do you understand modular arithmetic?

Comment: Yes , i understand what you are saying,may be i should think before writing anything .

Comment: Can you please elaborate how did you find $H_{2k} - H_k$,and how did you use the harmonic number to prove the divisibility ?

Comment: @MohammedAl-mubark I've elaborated on getting to $H_{2k}-H_k.$ The easiest way to understand what I've written is to interpret everything as elements in the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and the fraction $\frac{1}{i}$ denotes the inverse of $i$ in that field. Do you know much about fields? If not, try googling "modulo arithmetic with fractions" and understanding that.